# Solution want- Caused By:Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am not able to create the Session Factory Bean. If I block the session factory bean in my spring config file then it works file. If I comment out the session factory bean then it's showing this error. Seeking your help

Error--

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
```

Spring-Servlet.XML----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.as.order" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="ds"/>
        </property>  
    </bean> 
    <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
      <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</value>
      </property>
      <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
      <property name="password"><value>root</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.as.order.vo" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>     
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

Controller---

```
package com.as.order.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.as.order.service.OrderService;
import com.as.order.vo.Order;


@Controller
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService=null; 


    @RequestMapping(value="/orderentry")
    public ModelAndView orderEntry
    (@ModelAttribute("orderForm") Order order){
        return new ModelAndView("order");   
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/processorder", 
            method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processOrder(@ModelAttribute Order order){
        // step1
        System.out.println("Controller");
        // step2
        orderService.processOrder(order);
        // step3
        return "redirect:jsp/orderconfirmation.jsp";    
    }

    public OrderService getOrderService() {
        return orderService;
    }

    public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

}
```

Service--
Interface---

```
package com.as.order.service;

import com.as.order.vo.Order;

public interface OrderServiceIntf 
{
    public void processOrder(Order order);
}

Class--

package com.as.order.service;

import javax.validation.constraints.Null;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.OrderUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.as.order.dao.OrderDAOIntf;
import com.as.order.vo.Order;

@Service
public class OrderService implements OrderServiceIntf {
    @Autowired
    OrderDAOIntf orderDAO = null;

    @Override
    public void processOrder(Order order) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Service");
        orderDAO.processOrder(order);
    }

    public OrderDAOIntf getOrderDAO() {
        return orderDAO;
    }

    public void setOrderDAO(OrderDAOIntf orderDAO) {
        this.orderDAO = orderDAO;
    }
}
```

DAO-
 Interface--

```
package com.as.order.dao;

import com.as.order.vo.Order;

public interface OrderDAOIntf 
{
    public void processOrder(Order order);
}
```

Class--

```
package com.as.order.dao;

import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.as.order.vo.Order;

@Repository
public class OrderHibernateDAO implements OrderDAOIntf {


    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void processOrder(Order order) {
        System.out.println("DAO");
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(order);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Web XML--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring-MVC_Hibernate_with_Annotation1</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/spring</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/spring-form</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVafC.jpg
```

Comment: I am still facing this error seeking some solution....

Comment: Still seeking help about this issue...

Comment: Still not able to solve. Could anyone kindly help me?

Comment: is there anything I am missing?